# Deleting rows permanently from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How do you permanently remove rows from pandas dataframe?
For example:
I have a spreadsheet that has columns with headers, but has some info in the top 4 and bottom 2 rows that I don't want.
So I use:

```
            dataSet = pd.read_excel(excelFile)
            dataSet.drop(dataSet.head(4).index,inplace=True)
            dataSet.drop(dataSet.tail(2).index,inplace=True)
            rowCount = dataSet.shape[0]
            for a in range(rowCount):
                newPatientName = dataSet.iloc[a][0]
                print(newPatientName)
```

This works as expected by not including the info at top and bottom of spreadsheet.
However, when I do this later in the code:

```
            columnList = []
            for col in dataSet.columns:
                columnList.append(col)
            print(columnList)
```

It prints:

```
['Fab Tracking (w Completed) Report', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 3', 'Unnamed: 4', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6', 'Unnamed: 7', 'Unnamed: 8', 'Unnamed: 9']
```

Where `Fab Tracking (w Completed) Report'` is the rows I thought I deleted above? And the columns have no names... What am I missing here.

I also tried `dataSet = dataSet[4:-2]`

Image of spreadsheet:
[image]

**EDIT:**
After some comments below of people asking if I am deleting columns not rows I posted a picture of the spreadsheet.
If I manually edit this sheet in excel and delete the top 4 rows, then run: `dataSet.columns` it will give me the names of the column headers. But I don't want to have to open the spreadsheet everytime to do this. I want pandas to remove or ignore the top 4 **rows** so that I can get the names of the headers

Comment: `for col in dataSet.columns:` sounds like **columns** to me, not **rows**. Also, you can do `dataSet = dataSet.iloc[4:-2]` for quick dropping.

Comment: Pandas `dataframe.drop` defaults `inplace` to false. This means you need to set the result equal to something. Or set `inplace=True`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: Please see edits. I am not trying to remove columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas, the column names or headers are persistent and do not change upon removal/appending of rows. If you're trying to completely ignore the first 4 rows of the file, you can use the skiprows parameter in pd.read_excel like this -

```
pd.read_excel(excelFile, skiprows=4)
```

Followed by dropping the last 2 rows using -

```
dataSet = dataSet[:-2]
```

It's also quicker to use `columnList=list(dataSet.columns)` if you're trying to create a list of column names.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to delete columns, or rows?

If you want to delete columns:

```
dataSet.drop('Fab Tracking (w Completed) Report', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

After running this you will get the output you want when you run your for loop.

If you want to delete rows, then the code you have is fine. `dataSet.drop(dataSet.head(4).index,inplace=True)`

Right now your for loop is iterating over column names, not rownames.